# Hello world ends with 'linker command failed'. g++, OpenGL, Macbook with m1 chip

Tags: c++, opengl, g++, glfw, apple-m1

Macbook Air 2020, m1 chip, macOS 12.1 Monterey. No XCode. Though I have XCode Command Line tools.

I'm trying out OpenGL. I installed it: `brew install glfw`. I wrote this test.cpp:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
int main(void)
{
    
    GLFWwindow* window;

    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    return 0;

}
```

In Terminal, I run `g++ -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glfw/3.3.6/include -o ./test ./test.cpp`

And get this error: `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

What should I do?

Comment: Add a -l (minus-EL) option for the library that contains glfwInit.

Comment: You set the include directory but you failed to link to the glfw libraries

Comment: `g++ -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glfw/3.3.6/include -o ./helloworld ./test.cpp -lglfw -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit` worked